# How to add more than one repetitions to a request when using SOAP UI?

Tags: soapui

I'm using SOAP UI to perform API testing. When I make a new request it has the option: `<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->`. I need to add another repetition into this request so I copy the first and paste.
When I run the request, only the first is responsed, the second that I copied is not submitted and there's no result for it.
Please see the image for more details.

[image]

The HTML of this request is as below:

[image]

Comment: Image that was attached already contains multiple `Order` elements. What is the problem that you face?

Comment: could you please add my skype so that we can chat together more easily? I really appreciate that. Or leave your email and I will contact you. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the prefix namespace for the `<Order>` element. The namespace is needed to identify the type of the element, it's not for arbitrary use and needs to be defined in your XML, so in your case probably the correct XML looks like (despite the fact that I don't see your namespaces and your xsd in the question):

```
<mli:Orders>
   <mli:Order>...</mli:Order>
   <mli:Order>...</mli:Order>
</mli:Orders>
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**:

If as I see in the XML in your comments `<Order>` comes from `mli1:` prefix, use this instead of `mli:`, anyways my advice remains the same, don't change from one `<Order>` to another since it's the same object. So probably the `<mli:Orders>` must be something like:

```
<mli:Orders>
       <mli1:Order>...</mli1:Order> 
       <mli1:Order>...</mli1:Order> 
</mli:Orders>
```

Comment: <mli:Orders>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
<mli1:Order ser:Id="?" ser:Ref="?">
<!--Optional:-->
<mli2:CreatedBy>?</mli2:CreatedBy>
                  <!--Optional:-->
<mli1:ActionTypeId>?</mli1:ActionTypeId>
<!--Optional:-->
<mli1:UnitPrice>?</mli1:UnitPrice>
</mli1:Order>
</mli:Orders>

Comment: as orginial the request only as below:

Comment: could you please add my skype so that we can chat together more easily? I really appreciate that. Or leave your email and I will contact you. Thanks a lot

Comment: @UyênLê Instead of share our contacts it's better that you ask a new question explaining the errors you face, what do you want to achieve, what did you try a sample XML and XSD if it's necessary. There are a lot of great programmers around so you'll have more chances to have a good answer if you post a detailed question than emailing it to me.

Comment: Thank you very much @albciff